# como ocultar usuario dentro de un modal

Tags: javascript, php, modal, materialize

hola amigos este tengo un proyecto que estoy realizando en php puro y pues cree un modal con materialize que oculte el id de los empleados por fallecimiento o por renuncia y despido y quiero que cuando le de click en baja se oculte la linea con todos los datos del usuario y espero que me ayuden en verdad
eh intentado de muchas formas y ninguna ah funcionado.

```html
 <!-- Modal Baja -->
      <div id="modal2" class="modal" style="width: 40%; height: 100%;">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <h4 class="center">Baja Empleado</h4>
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i>
              <input type="text" class="datepicker">
              <label for="icon_prefix">Fecha de Baja</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <select name="motivos" id="motivos" onchange="seleccionarMotivo();">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Motivo</option>
                <option value="fallecimiento">Fallecimiento</option>
                <option value="renuncia">Renuncia</option>
                <option value="despido">Despido</option>
              </select>
            </div>
                <input id="andphone" type="text"  style="display: none" placeholder="Renuncia"/>
                <input id="espphone" type="text"  style="display: none" placeholder="Despido"/>
          </div>
          <div class="center">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light green accent-4 btn" href="../views/lista_Rh.php">Cancelar</a>
           <a  class="waves-effect waves-light green accent-4 btn" href="../views/lista_Rh.php"><i class="material-icons left">arrow_downward</i>Baja</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ponle un evento al elemento que contenga el id, luego cambias su estilo de visibilidad.

Comment: me podrias decir como y en que parte va creo es en javascript??

Comment: En un momento elaboro una respuesta, ahora estoy algo ocupado :(

Comment: si esta bien no te preocupes!!

Comment: podrias decirme donde se encuentra "baja" en donde deseas hacer el click

Comment: esta antes de que termine el modal

Comment: Lo siento pero podrías facilitarme el id o la clase